R package object not exported?
I'm trying to load he package epiR but I'm getting the message:

Error: object 'match_fonts' is not exported by 'namespace:systemfonts'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'epiR'

What (if any) is the best way to handle this? I'm currently trying to downgrade until I find a version that loads
I'm currently trying to downgrade until I find a version that loads
ETA: R version 4.3.3, Windows 10 (not sure what other info might be helpful)

looks like from version 1.0.6 to 1.1.0 they changed the name of that function

I don't have a problem loading the current version of epiR in R 4.4.1.  Maybe an R update would help?

I had the same error message when trying to install the package gdtools. I found that installing the package systemfonts worked. I was then able to install gdtools without hitting the error.
